# What languages are perceived as classy or fancy to French speakers?

Tags: histoire, comparaison-de-langues, emprunts, registre

In English, this might be demonstrated by using the word *boutique* rather than *shop*, or by saying *au contraire* rather than *on the contrary*, because to English speakers French is commonly perceived as high-class or fancy (at least in American/British English) and sometimes that's the feel the speaker is going for.

If French speakers were to substitute in a foreign word for no reason other than that it could be perceived as more classy or prestigious, which language or languages would it tend to come from?

---

If, after Aerovistae's able editing of the original question as above, the sense of the question is still unclear, I want to emphasize the fact that words like 'boutique' or 'au contraire' have a unique status in English in that they

- sound distinctly foreign and
- replace more ordinary words of the same meaning.

There are words to sound more learned or pedantic without sounding foreign, e.g. 'lachrymose' for 'tearful.'  Others don't have a more ordinary alternative, e.g. 'gestalt' in 'gestalt psychology' or 'allegro' and 'andante.'

These 'fancy foreign sounding' words in English are predominantly from French.  It's very possible that French does not have an equivalent, and that would be an answer.

In other words:  Whatever may be the shortcomings of this question, it is not vague.

Comment: I'm going stab a guess that the answer is "English and Italian." Interesting question.

Comment: I disagree with @Aerovistae, using English words when not really needed is considered cool and trendy (or of course ridiculous and too much if you don't like this), but not "classy" or "fancy" (I think using German, like in philosophy or music, is more something like what you are talking about).

Comment: I was just speculating. Looking forward to actual answers.

Comment: @Aerovistae. Thanks for the extensive edit. I would like my original title to survive if only in comments:  "What do the French do when they need a French word?"

Comment: I'm afraid this question might bring a lot of primarily opinion-based answers. And this not withstanding the fact that "classy" or "fancy" would need to be defined first, where would you draw the barrier with "pedantic", "educated", etc. ? Why not rather discuss it [chez Cosette](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35471665#35471665).

Comment: I would say Latin words...

Comment: @Catomic I don't understand what you mean by  "What do the French do when they need a French word?". Do you mean when a word doesn't exist in French but exists in another language (e.g. computer terms that only exist in English) ?

Comment: @Laure. I think the sense got edited out when Aerovisatae took *sa main capable* to the question. I was thinking of a poor French shopkeeper who would like to charge double for everything just by naming his shop a *boutique*, but can't. (To all his customers, that only sounds like a *shop*.)

Comment: @NathanCoustenoble I think you could be right, Latin was used by nobility in France, just like french in England. If you make an answer explaining in detail why it's still a little different, I'd upvote it.

Comment: @Catomic Did you notice I started discussing the question *Chez Cosette*?

Comment: @Laure. Yes I read everything you wrote. Thank you. Also the feature is new to me. I'll have to explore.

Comment: There could be endless answers & points of views so I don't think the question & answer format is a good one. As I hinted, it's also a highly controversial issue in some academic circles.

Comment: @Jylo Here is your answer :p

Comment: +1, especially for the way you originally described what you’re after.  Granted, the original title was confusing, but I interpreted it to mean: “Do the French have a particular go-to foreign language when, for whatever reason, they think a foreign word or phrase would serve them better than a French word/phrase?"  I also interpreted your original “supposedly more prestigious” to mean “exotic” or even the more neutral “eye-catching,” which, imo, go well w/your “shop” vs “boutique” example. Anyway, here in Williamsburg, Va, the goal is apparently “quaintness” so we see a lot of “olde shoppes”!

Comment: Fancy-sounding words are not predominantly from French: they originate in Latin and ancient Greek, not French. But what is a fancy word anyway?? It depends on who's talking to whom about  what. Of course, they are loads of words from French: tennis, which comes from tenez, which was said on the original grass tennis courts (royals playing tennis), for Here you go. When hitting a ball to the opponent. And today, the French say le tennis.

Comment: @PapaPoule. Thanks for excavating me. I wanted to avoid characterizing the phenomenon too definitely and perhaps prejudicing the outcome, but from the 'viewed' count it seems the Community got the question it wanted.

Comment: Does anyone know why this question got so many views? It has about 30 times as much as other questions asked at the same time. I think it's because it got in "hot network questions", but how did it get here in the first place?

Comment: @TeleportingGoat You may find some clues at [What formula should be used to determine “hot” questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11602/139866) etc.

Comment: @Lambie. Who said anything about originating? That's not even relevant. *Boutique* and *apothecary* come from the same Greek root, but only *boutique* does the job it does in English because it is perceived 'as French.'

Comment: Before you ask what foreign language the French consider "classy", you have to consider why many Anglophones regard French as a "classy" language to begin with. Simply put, it's because of the Norman Conquest of England in 1066. Because of this one event, the English picked up thousands of words of French vocabulary, which, coming from their new nobility, were considered upper-class almost from the start. This perception persists to this day. For an idea of what English might've been like had the Battle of Hastings gone the other way, have a look [here](https://youtu.be/IIo-17SIkws).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about the French language, but about languages other than French, and it is about culture and society, in fact. This questions was closed for the same reason: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25031/are-people-in-belgium-equally-likely-to-speak-dutch-as-they-are-to-speak-french, so this one should be closed too.

Comment: @Frank. The 'close' count had gone up to 4 at one time before climbing to zero again. Let's see what this new cycle brings us.

Comment: @Catomic - quite an imperfect system, with a lot of irrationality, subjectivity and false arguments going around: the recent question about the distribution of French in Belgium was deemed inappropriate because about culture and society rather than language, but this didn't fell to the same axe. Quite inconsistent. Note: I would have no problem keeping both questions,or removing both, but not one but not the other.

Comment: @Frank I applaud/agree w/your efforts to call attention to the inconsistent treatment of the 2 questions at issue, but imo, effort should be focused on reopening the closed one (which I’ve just voted to reopen based on your good post in “Meta”) rather than on closing this 1. In addition to your well-reasoned claim of inconsistency, I see the attracting & keeping of interesting & interested users as essential to the health/viability of this forum & discouraging users, esp. new ones, by closing their arguably OT questions in the name of strict adherence to the rules is counterintuitive at best.

Comment: I didn't realize you could vote to reopen a question. Indeed, better to keep both. As for the "rules" they are clearly not interpreted the same by everybody. I would err on the side of interpreting them broadly, just as you say.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I really don't think there's an equivalent. French has a particular status for other countries, but I can't see a language that would be the same for French. Not at the same level at least.

Maybe some German words, for philosophy and such, but that's pretty much it. It makes you sound cultivated, but not necessarily "fancy" (plus you really *need* to be cultivated to use German words in French).

Also a bit of Italian, but apart from music and coffee, I don't think it's used that much.

Possibly Greek and Latin too.

All in all, I think they are perceived like they are in English. I can't think of a cross-domain language, whose words you can use to sound fancy.

(I'll add that if you use English words for everything you might sound condescending and full of yourself)

Comment: My choosing this answer obviously does not signal 'agreement' because I don't know enough to agree. It however seems to sum up the overall sentiment scattered across all answers and comments. Thanks.

Comment: That's how Stack Exchange works :) You don't have to point out that you asked the question every time you accept an answer.

Comment: Mostly Latin (mainly expressions) and Italian (almost only for food and music/opera). But I'd like to add French itself too: you can use classier and fancier words and sentence structure and achieve a similar effect to using French words in English IMHO.

Comment: I'd say though that we do perceive British English as pretty fancy (you know, tea and so on (well, tea)), while we tend to make (kindly) fun of American English, that we usually depict as rude (f*ck and so on). You could find some people having the habit of using "my dear" or "darling", maybe even "milady", but nowadays it would likely be just for fun. On the other hand, we love insults from European countries, especially Spain and Italy, and Germany as well.

Comment: While I agree with latin and greek, IMHO a good way to sound fancy in French is to use tenses that are not common in verbal communication, like the _passé simple_ or the _passé antérieur_

Comment: When a French speaker uses too much Anglicisms, he is said to make his "Van damme" as a reference to Jean Claude Van Damme, however that underlyingly mean he sounds retarded. It appears curiously that this is tolerated for traders and advertisment creators.

Comment: @v.oddou About traders and advertisment creators, it's not *tolerated*, it's just that, culturally, these jobs are depicted as occupyied by condescendants full of pride, that use english words to create an artificial complexity about their job, and to show that they work *à l'international*. A very good representation of this cultural belief is [*les publicitaires* by *les inconnus*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HgKXN_Uw2ME), where advertisers mix french and poor english in a so exacerbated manner it become ridiculous.

Comment: the answer is that for French it would be French too :-D

Comment: I once read a text where the author used the word "bambin". In my ears, this Italian word sounded fancy in a French text. The same holds for latin, e.g. "ad libitum".

Comment: @user66288 "*Bambin*" exists in [French](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bambin). It does come from Italian though. I've seen "*bambino*" or "*bambini*" used however, with a similar effect to the one you describe.

Answer (score 42):

I'll add my two cents from a translation angle, even though I don't have a solid answer.

This is an excellent question from the point of view of a translator, because it gets at an issue translators sometimes face: multilingual sources where the use of a different language in the source carries a particular weight but might be meaningless to the target language speaker.

For example, in an English movie where a character uses the odd French phrase to sound fancy, what does he use in the French version? As Catomic rightly points out, for him to use French would be to miss the nuance, and as everyone else has added, for him to simply invert and use English would be to defeat the nuance entirely. Whether Latin or German are okay substitutes others would know better.

But the whole question is very bound up in a difficult problem... [David Bellos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Bellos) in the excellent [*Is That a Fish in Your Ear?*](https://www.amazon.ca/That-Fish-Your-Ear-Translation/dp/0865478767) explains a similar case at length:

> *The Great Escape* ... tells the almost-true story of a mass break-out from a POW camp in Germany. The leader of the plot [Bartlett] has good language skills in French and German and teams up with MacDonald, who has only English, to get from the tunnel exit to the Channel coast. Camouflaged as a pair of French businessmen, they are in line to board a bus that will take them further on. There's a security check. Bartlett bluffs his way through in very plausible French and German. ... The canny policeman wishes the pair of them 'Good luck' — in English. MacDonald, still on the step, instinctively turns round, smiles and blurts out, 'Thank you' — and that's the end of his great escape. **It's not the linguistic meanings of the policeman's expression or MacDonald's response that catch the fugitives out, but the symptomatic meaning of the language used.**
>
> **It is not possible to reproduce the symptomatic meaning of the use of a given language in a language other than the one being used.** You can't use Finnish, for example, to re-create the force of 'speaking-in-English-when-escaping-from-a-German-prison-camp'. In the French-language version of the film, 'good luck' and 'thank you' stay in English — French audiences are expected to recognize the sounds of English and to know the symptomatic meaning of using English in war-time Germany. But in versions intended for audiences for whom spoken English, French, and German just have the sound of 'Average West European', **the overall meaning of the sequence can't be saved by not translating the spoken sentences (as in French) or by translating them, since the use of any language other than English would miss the point. Some other layer or channel of communication has to be added**, such as a subtitle or surtitle. The supplementary stream would give a metalinguistic description of the utterance, such as 'The German policeman is speaking English', or 'The authorities use the native language of the fugitive, who foolishly replies in like manner.' Would that count as translation? ...
>
> [Emphasis added]

The point being made here is that the metalinguistic information — in the case of this question, "What a pithily inserted French phrase sounds like to English ears" — may not even be translatable by a substitution and may have to be explained explicitly. "Je constatai qu'il avait choisi le terme le plus ésotérique / qu'il avait choisi pour compléter son énoncé un terme du latin ; il ne put point ignorer que moi je ne le comprenais pas ..." Rough, but starts to get at the significance.

Sometimes a paradigm shift instead of a note is used instead. Such paradigm shifts are tricky to get right, but can be used to more naturally translate the cultural or metalinguistic information of an utterance. For example, here's a common trick used between French and English translations from the wonderful Québecois movie [Monsieur Lazhar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monsieur_Lazhar), originally in French and here given with the English subtitles:

> Claire : Ça va ? *How are you?*
>
> Bashir : Oui, ça va. Et vous ? *Fine, thanks. And you, Ms Martel?*
>
> Claire : Bien, merci. On peut se tutoyer. *Good, thanks. You can call me Claire.*

Here, as you can see, of course, the paradigm "Vouvoyer vs. tutoyer" has been shifted to the English "Last-name basis vs. first-name basis". Is it a perfect match? No, but it's pretty satisfactory. Other ones, such as the case with the use of different languages in the source, are harder!

I know this doesn't answer the real question directly, but hopefully it added some perspective. :)

---

Much later addition: I just discovered this Rita Moreno (as "Tiffany Gonzales") sketch from The Muppet Show. Here's a lovely and hilarious example comparing [an English speaker with a Spanish accent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JL55XUxifX4) and [a French speaker with a Spanish accent](https://youtu.be/Wd3v7PEL8Tg?t=142) — a rare occasion where the joke seems to be perfectly preserved.

Comment: Great example with tutoyer!

Comment: @LukeSawczak - c'est un peu ce que je disais ailleurs: les mots viennent avec une série de connotations, ils font partie d'un réseau sémantique, et ces réseaux sémantiques dans lesquels les mots sont insérés sont parfois sans équivalent dans une autre langue. Ce qu'un mot évoque dans une certains langue ne peut pas toujours être reproduit dans une autre langue.

Comment: Oui, c'est exact. Alors ce qui reste c'est de voir à quel point une stratégie de "transposition sémantique" donnée (si je peux employer ce terme-là ici) peut nous servir de solution. Lesquels des problèmes de connotation dite intraduisible peut-on pallier à l'aide d'un équivalent approximatif, et lesquels exigent plutôt qu'on en donne l'explication explicite (pour ne pas dire qu'on les abandonne !)

Comment: Excellent answer - do you know how the scene does go in *The Great Escape* in French? I think if I had to come up with something, I'd simply subtitle: '[Speaking in English]' - but I wonder if they came up with something more clever? Perhaps since the words 'good, luck, thank, you' are simple it could be done in English; with the bluffing done in the opposite of French/German that the translation is for, and subtitled?

Comment: In French, the exchange is the same (see 2:05:00 into [this video](https://youtu.be/28-2IqMt_Xc?t=2h5m4s)). I think Bellos is right that this is because "French audiences are expected to recognize the sounds of English and to know the symptomatic meaning of using English in war-time Germany." Of course, English is such a privileged language today that maybe that gamble could be made in almost any version, but you can imagine a similar scene where, say, the escapee meant to speak Spanish but spoke in Portuguese -- I suspect most of us would need the explicit reading of what's going on then. :)

Comment: Dad read an Italian novel in which much of the dialogue was in Sicilian.  His wife read it in translation, and he was disappointed that it was all put into plain English.  I suggested that the Sicilian dialogue could be translated as Scots.  Dad chuckled at that for years.

Comment: Puis on tutoie le Nôtre Père mais Je vous salue Marie.  Enfin il y a Miss Piggy: "If conversation is a dying art, you've killed it!"  vs. "Si la conversation est en train de mourir, c'est elle l'assassin !" Morte. De. Rire.

Answer (score 21):

Probably Latin.

Some examples of Latin words or phrases that a native French speaker could use to sound posh:

- *ab abrupto* instead of *abruptement*
- *ad honores* instead of *pour l'honneur*
- *ergo* instead of *donc*

A caricature of this is found in the Astérix series where Latin phrases are used by Romans as a Frenchman would use them when they want to sound posh.

Alternatively one might use words with a distinct Latin or Greek root. This tendency is joked about with several words that are deliberately made from Greek and Latin roots to obscure the meaning – *capillotracté* for *tiré par les cheveux*, *xyloglossie* for *langue de bois*, ...

Comment: +1 pour la xyloglossie, non pas que son emploie ne devienne tendance ...

Comment: Je crois que je vais commencer à l'utiliser. On va voir si ça me rend "_classy_".

Comment: Yes for Latin! Also in the fact that (once?) common Latin expressions are being replaced with (possibly debatable) French ones, such as "in fine" becoming "au final" and many more. This does give a formal tone when sticking to the former version. Here's [a good list of Latin expressions commonly used](https://www.etudes-litteraires.com/langue-francaise/expressions-latines.php).

Answer (score 18):

There is no such language in France.

---

I think we need to take a step back:

> Why is French perceived as "fancy" or "classy"?

From the Wikipedia [History of French: Modern French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_French#Modern_French) article:

> From the 17th to the 19th centuries, France was the leading power of Europe; thanks to this, together with the influence of the [Enlightenment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_Enlightenment), French was the lingua franca of educated Europe, especially with regards to the arts, literature, and diplomacy; monarchs like Frederick II of Prussia and Catherine the Great of Russia could both not just speak and write in French, but in most excellent French. **The Russian, German and Scandinavian Courts spoke French as their main or official language, regarding their national languages as the language of the peasants.**

I think that this is where the idea that French is the language of elite sprang from: French was used by the nobility, scientists, artists... everybody that was somebody.

---

It is also interesting that, as remarked in comments, English itself promotes French as a fancy language.

In 1066 [William the Conqueror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_the_Conqueror), then Duke of Normandy, gained his title by conquering England. He installed his fellow Normans as the nobles of England.

This means that much like above, from then on French was the language of the nobility and high class. In turn, it means that even in modern English, French retains a special place, and French borrowed words are generally perceived as more refined than their Anglo-Saxon counterparts.

Since then, English has thoroughly overtaken French in terms of number of speakers; but in doing so it has also promoted French as a fancy language.

---

Also notable, you can find a "Lycée français" (literally, French highschool) in many countries. Generally, they are frequented by the children of French diplomats or expatriates, but also, and crucially, by some of the children of the highest class of the country in which they are.

These schools not only promote French, but also reflect positively on French and France as they give excellent education<sup>1</sup> to their (elite) students, further reinforcing that France and Excellence go hand in hand.

<sup>1</sup> *Excellent ~French~ education, with French history and culture having a pro-eminent place.*

---

More generally, this extends to French culture. Considering its relatively small size (~70 millions inhabitants only), France has a disproportionate influence in the Luxury market (restaurants, fashion, ...) and in arts (Festival International du Film de Cannes, for example). The French Riviera is a prized destination, with Monaco just nearby, ...

All this contributes to France having a dream-like quality.

---

The only language which achieved such status in France was Latin, which was spoken by the nobility and clergy. However, during the French Revolution (1789), the nobility and clergy lost some of their shine to say the least.

And even then, Latin had been losing ground for some time. The French Academy was established by Richelieu in 1634, Rabelais was publishing books [in French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gargantua_and_Pantagruel) in the 16th century.

The only current language that has such a widespread use as French is English, however France and England have been at odds for a long time (you may have heard of the [Hundred's Years War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hundred_Years'_War)). Recognizing that English is "better" than French is thus unlikely, it would be conceding victory somehow.

Comment: "French was the lingua franca."  Ya don't say!

Comment: +1 for the history lesson!

Comment: Missing from the above is the effect of William the Conqueror taking the English throne and installing his Norman buddies as noblemen. This created the situation where French was literally "noble" and "high class". Virtually without exception, where English has borrowed words from French and retained Anglo-Saxon synonyms, the latter are seen as "low class", "crude", "vulgar" while the French equivalents are "refined", "high class", etc.

Comment: @MontyHarder: I suppose that would be an influence for the UK, but I don't think it would influence the other countries (Russia, Scandinavia, Germany, ...) as much the Age of Enlightenment.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I don't see this as a criticism of your answer but as an extension. Monty Harder's point influences the whole English language, the third largest language by number of native speakers .And i can say people I meet in China, with English as their second language, know that using French words is fancy in English.

Comment: @ColinMcLarty: I didn't take it as a criticism, don't worry. I also didn't realize that this would extend from the UK to ALL English speakers though, I thought it was anecdotical. It's strange (for me) to consider English has a vehicle of the "French is classy", but of course languages also carry their culture. I'll see how I can include this.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Did William the Conqueror actually speak "French"? The historical situation might have been a bit more complicated, as I think he spoken _norman_, which was only one of the _langues d'oïl_ then spoken. At the same time, Eleanor of Aquitaine would have brought a _langue d'oc_ to the court.

Comment: @Frank: I would expect he was speaking *some* French, the Duchy of Normandy was founded in 911, or 150 years before the conquest of England, that's quite a few generations. Note that the *langues d'oïl* are likely closer to French than the *langues d'oc*, as the former included Parisian while the latter didn't.

Comment: @Frank The language William the Conqueror spoke was considered to be French just like the other *langue d'oil* dialects.

Comment: @jlliagre - Historically, when does the term "French" (language) appear? At the time of William the Conqueror, there were _sevral_ langues d'oïls, rather than one "French language", and I was just reading that up to the 12th century, people called their language "Romance" rather than "French". But anyway, that's getting away from the question of the OP, and it doesn't change the argument that "Romance" words appeared in England with WIlliam the Conqueror.

Answer (score 4):

English, by far.

Some time ago the French would adopt English words when there was no pithy French equivalent, such as "marketing," "sandwich," or "weekend" for example.  That is just practical linguistic cross-pollination and has nothing to do with the question.

But nowadays they grab all kinds of simple words even if there is a perfectly good French word.  Some of these are French words (stopper, for example) but what I heard or read was not the correct French sense of the word but the English sense.  For example:  *Si t'il plait stopper crier si fort.*  That is *not* how *stopper* is used in correct French.  Google thinks that phrase is fine.  A good French teacher will reach for their big red pen.  Other examples:

- [acceptable French word] -> [what the French use instead]
- arrêter -> *stopper*
- vérifier -> *checker*
- diviser -> *splitter*
- réviser -> *updater*

... with all the -er verbs pronounced properly, "stop-ay", like they're Canadian, eh?

Personally I blame MTV.

[later on...]

- [acceptable French word] -> [what the French use instead]
- plage -> *beach*
- gastronomie -> *fooding*
- dépliant -> *flyer*
- autocollant -> *sticker*

Then I hit the Internet and found much, much more. Here is one link but please, look for yourselves:
http://www.topito.com/top-15-des-mot-anglais-que-les-francais-utilisent-sans-raison-valable

This answer, I admit, has a broad interpretation of "fancy" and "classy," as some of you pointed out.  But I suspect that people who say *J'irai à la beach* also use "fancy," "classy", "cool" and "hip" interchangeably.

This answer is also open to the *that's-already-a-French-word* criticism.  But I suspect that if you research the word that you will uncover the same situation that this question presents:  The word was adopted from English for no other reason than it was "classy" or "cool", or whatever, and that there was a perfectly acceptable alternative in French.

Comment: I'm going to work on the list, I'm sure there are more juicy examples, I just have to keep my ears open.  Stay tuned...

Comment: Those do not make you sound classy, it gives the feeling of someone working in a big company, with English-speaking clients. I see that as a lack of respect because the person using them basically forgot or didn't care to switch back to French.

Comment: You are giving French derived from English and not foreign words as such, which is what OP is asking for.  I also disagree when English sounding "high-class" or "fancy". English is now the *lingua franca* that everyone  speaks, or is supposed to speak. In France both *musée* & *museum* are used as French words, but they are not interchangeable.

Comment: @Teleporting Goat.  I agree, to my ears it doesn't sound classy at all.  But the question is about how French people perceive the word.  All of these examples are culled from entirely French contexts.

Comment: A "stopper"  in English is a noun (and cannot be a verb) and means so who stops, or  a cork. *Stopper* in French can only be a verb.

Comment: Museum can arguably be defined as a Latin word, not a English one. *Splitter, updater* (and *upgrader, débriefer*) ar not English words (precisely verbs) but neologisms having a English root.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Sometimes (in France) I'm surprised to see English words used inside a French sentence in advertising on a public billboard. Maybe that's "hip" or something, if not "classy"?

Comment: @Laure. I believe you misread the answer so I modified it.  Your point is misplaced.  In my example the person should have written musée but instead they wrote museum, without an accent.  In the other example, stopper, the person used stopper in the broarder English sense of "to stop", not in the narrower sense of the French "stopper."  You were not there when I heard/read these examples so please believe me.

Comment: @Laure, the only difference between "French derived from [another language]" or a "foreign word" is chronological.  Words that used to be foreign but were adopted into the French language are valid examples to the answers people have given.

Comment: @ssimm - I would say that these English words are used not because they are "classy" or "cool", but just because it's convenient, and it's in the environment already (MTV, as you say, but that's just one example).

Comment: I highly doubt that museum is used over musée.

Comment: English would be a good answer if the question were about a cool/hip nuance. Maybe "fancy" and "classy" have ambiguous meanings, but what isn't ambiguous is that *élan*, *raison d'être*, *joie de vivre*, and so on don't sound "hip" to to English speakers but elevated and cultured. Whereas *stopper*, *fooding*, *chekcer* likely don't ring quite the same to a French speaker. :p

Comment: @ChrisW You'll see those words in ads targeted mostly towards the young. It's targetting, not anything "fancy". Other people usually find those ads incomprehensible, hip or even lazy, yes. But fancy? No.

Comment: French never use museum because musée is shorter. The only exception would be "museum d'histoire naturelle".

Comment: Using (too much) franglais (english words that have been adapted to french) will make you sound like a moron who can't use the correct word
or will make your interlocutor believe you're using "big" words to try to fool/impress him.

Comment: English has become **trendy** indeed, with internet there are tons of English words widely used by French people now, especially the young generation and the people working in international companies or digital fields. But it is not at all *fancy* or *classy* for French people.

Comment: Also, the word *muséum* in French comes from Latin ([source](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mus%C3%A9um)), not from English (the English word also comes from Latin actually).

Comment: "Google thinks that phrase is fine" - why do you think that? If you're talking about GT (and other machine-translators), generally these will do their best to translate whatever it is you're inputting, regardless of how implausible or off-the-mark your original word choice is.

Answer (score 3):

French is considered the classy language in many countries.
As for why, I would say that it is mainly because French's ancestors used to rule over England, and thus it became correlated with nobility. (maybe part of it is how french sounds too).

The same goes for us in France. Our upperclass language have been for a very long time latin. Until the last century, it was a must for literate people. Not surprising considering how long the Roman Empire ruled what became France.
**Latin** has been slowly losing its appeal recently, in favor of English mostly (I don't speak a word of Latin whereas I have a decent level of English), but English is less 'classy' than 'cool'.

And Latin is also more correlated with science whereas French is more poetic (?)

Voilà ! (:p)

Comment: us frenches?? literate people?? That means people who can read and write?? Our upperclasss language?

Comment: @Lambie Yep it used to be the case

Comment: @Nathan Coustenoble I was not aware that the "upperclass language" in France was "Latin" "for a very long time". Perhaps you should qualify that historically.

Comment: @Lambie, "noble" est surment pas le mot correct, mais seul les gens qui pouvait se payer une éducation (les nobles/bourgeois?) apprenait à lire et écrire et ça incluait lire et écrire le latin. Le ecclésiastiques avait aussi la chance d'obtenir une éducation, là aussi en latin.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't  French equivalent of that because the French consider French to be the fanciest language in the world (even fancy doesn't have an exact equivalent, they might say sophisticated or beautiful).

This is not unique to the French, the Italians believe "la bella lingua" to be the most beautiful language in the world, and many other countries will too.

It's worth noting that use of Italian, Latin and Spanish phrases are also deemed "fancy", though not with the same prevalence as French. One possible explanation is that any use of a foreign language phrase indicates a certain level of culture, although this tends to be restricted to Latin languages (there aren't many Chinese or German phrases, and the few there are don't come across as "fancy")

French is seen as classy in Britain is because French  was the language spoken by parts of the upper classes, while the lower classes spoke a mix of British and Saxon.

That's why many things have a French name when the thing is spoken of in polite society and the Saxon name is used in other segments of society:

- A sheep (Saxon word) on the farm, but at table it's mutton (from French mouton)
- A pig on the farm, but at table its pork

In some cases the Saxon word has being pushed out to the point of being rude. For example breeding in Dutch (a very Saxon language) is "fokken" and as you can guess what the English Saxon equivalent was. Your bum (or "tushy" if you're in USA) in Dutch is kont, which sounds similar to an English swear word.

With that knowledge it may be argued that the notion of a foreign language being superior to the native tongue (and therefore "classy") is a cultural peculiarity of English that arose from a push to brand the native language as "common" or vulgar, which in turn arose from the specific historical events. Therefore seeking an equivalent in the language of a country where that has not happened is rather futile.

Comment: I like the examples and the historical perspective, but not the notion that "French consider French to be the fanciest language in the world".

Comment: I didn't like saying that either, but I grew up in France as well as England, and people in both countries can be found to be proud of a great number of things, but pride in the superiority of language I found present in French but absent in the English (I'd say most feel neutral about it). This is personal observation however, so not very scientific or evidence based, but then insights into culture often can't be scientific.

Answer (score 2):

I think that pride (or vanity?) is the main reason that turns blind all the authors of the answers above, saying *there is no such fancy language in French*.

They are blind indeed, because - unfortunately! - it is more than obvious that English now has this role in French, particularly in the world of enterprises, and of course even more particularly in the world of technology, in the world of finance, and even in the world of arts, though one might have thought this one would have been spared.

So French people don't talk about `art de rue` but they mention `street art`, they don't say `mosaïque` any more, but `patchwork`, managers talk about `debriefing` instead of `compte-rendu`, `sandwich` instead of `casse-croûte`, `asset management` instead of `gestion de patrimoine`, `sponsoring` instead of `mécénat`, `digital` instead of `numérique`, `design` instead of `dessin` (though the English, here like often, comes from the French); `flirter` instead of `conter fleurette` (though the verb `to flirt` comes from `conter fleurette`) and so many more. I could fill dozens of pages!

In the big societies, you can see more and more often that the names of the jobs are given in English, though all employees are French speaking people, such as `Management Consulting Advisor`, `Asset Management Director`, etc...

These days, it's becoming more and more intrusive, like a cancer, I should say: even the Frenh acronyms are replaced by English ones: For example, most young people write "LOL" on their phone messages, instead of "MDR" (mort de rire).

And even grosser, it looks as if the world of universities itself began to consider that the French language is not serious enough for intellectual purpose! What has become of the ***Sorbonne***, that once enlightened the whole world ?! For example, the schools of commerce , still 25 years ago, called themselves `Ecole Supérieure de Commerce` (de Lyon, de Rouen, de Bordeaux ...) but now most of them have changed that name for `Business School` or `School of Business`, the most hallucinating being the ancient `Ecole Supérieure de Commerce de Dijon` that now calls itself `Burgundy School of Business`! Here, even the original name `Bourgogne` has been changed for `Burgundy` !

In the daily world of shopping, the society Carrefour has named its little shops that you can find in every town: `Carrefour Market` or `Carrefour City` (though `city` is merely the English adaptation of the French word `cité`)

Even worse, Christine Lagarde, present director of the FMI (*Fond Monétaire International*, or IMF in English), once was minister of finance in the government of Nicolas Sarkozy: In those days, she dared to publish official memorandums in English! as a minister of France !! Shouldn't that have been considered as a sign of treason? Yes, it should !

So please, don't say that English has not become a *fancy* language in French, because saying that, you just show how blind you are! You'd better start struggling about this progressive invasion of the French language by the English one: we can admit the enrichment of French by English when it gives really new concepts (hub, switch, week-end...) but we shouldn't accept the replacement of French words by English ones for concepts that French has already, should we?

Comment: Cultural capital or currency is really not the same thing as fanciness. The fact that you (and others) consider this a vulgarisation rather than an enrichment of the language is the proof. The asker is looking for a language that elicits the exact opposite reaction to yours. P.S. Un peu de courtoisie va tellement loin sur StackExchange.

Comment: I think you read me "en diagonale", because I'm precisely talking about "fanciness", and I show that, in this modern time in France, it has even become "overfanciness" or "hyperfanciness". It is this "hyper" that I dislike, not the opportunity to take a benefit from the fact that the Anglo-Saxon world has been the avant-garde of innovation for more than a century.

Comment: N'hésitez pas à "plusser" ce post argumenté qui cherche à réveiller les consciences face au naufrage linguistique qui est en train de se produire!

Answer (score 1):

I'm siding with Teleporting Goat and I don't think there is an equivalent. Greek and Latin could be it, but flaunting some classical knowledge is usually perceived as pedantic and show-off, so Greek and Latin don't quite work either, although they come close. English is not perceived as "classy" at all, but more as an unavoidable invader, IMHO.

Comment: How do you define a word as an "invasive" one?  For me the essence of the question rules out considering "invasive" words.  So, strip all those out, like tuning, for example, which is invasive, and I suspect there are still many English words that remain only because they are considered as "classy," more or less.

Comment: There might be a longstanding cultural bias against English as "classy", IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

As a native French, I don't think you will achieve your objective by just replacing words by other ones. As said before, French was the elite language all over Europe. My advice is : have a more-than-perfect syntax and grammar,  don't use english words when french ones are available, don't use gross words.

Comment: Il existe des mots dans d'autres langues qui ne correspondent à rien en français et ne peuvent être expliqués qu'au prix d'une longue périphrase. Si les participants comprennent tous le mot ou l'expression étrangère, il peut être efficace d'utiliser le mot étranger directement, en important du coup tout ce que l'expression implique (dans son contexte étranger) dans la conversation.

Comment: @Frank, l'importation de mots est souvent incorrect. Un bon exemple serait « Bazar ». C'est très rarement utilisé dans le premier sens du terme en France.

Comment: @AlexisWilke - c'est vrai, cela est possible aussi.

Answer (score 1):

English language situation against the French one is somewhat unique, and was already considered as such 700 years ago.

Here is what Robert of Gloucester wrote around 1300:

> *þe normans ne couþe speke þo bote hor owe speche
>   & speke french as hii dude at om & hor children dude also teche
>   so þat heiemen of þis lond þat of hor blod come
>   holdeþ alle þulk speche þat hii of hom nome
>   vor bote a man conne frenss me telþ of him lute
>   ac lowe men holdeþ to engliss & to hor owe speche ȝute.
>   ich wene þer ne beþ in al þe world contreyes none
>   þat ne holdeþ to hor owe speche bote engelond one
>   ac wel me wot uor to conne boþe wel it is
>   vor þe more þat a mon can þe more wurþe he is.*

which reads:

> The Normans not could speak then but their own speech
>   & spoke French as they did at home & their children did also teach
>   so that nobles of this land that come of their blood
>   hold all the same speech that they from them took
>   for unless a man knows French one counts of him little
>   but low men hold to English & to their own speech still.
>   I think there not is in all the world countries none
>   that not hold to their own speech but England alone
>   but well one knows for to understand both well it is
>   for the more that a man knows the more worthy he is.

Source: [History of the English Language, Middle English Handout](https://www.csun.edu/~sk36711/WWW/engl400/me1.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Je pense que c'est le français qui joue ce rôle en français. C'est possible grâce aux différents [registres de la langue](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registres_de_langue_en_fran%C3%A7ais), familier, courant ou soutenu.

Answer (score 0):

Latin and Greek. Classic languages.

Comment: The question seemed to be about the origins of words rather than languages in general. Some details or examples would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say Latin and Greek words and phrases are the ones you're looking for, but they tend to sound scholarly or pedantic rather than just classy.

Posh people (in my imagination, cause I only know very few) would just have a formal language, possibly with a few Latin expressions thrown in if they also belong to the previous categories.
They'd pay close attention to their grammar, and use a slightly older form of French. They'd avoid dropping the double-negation ("Je ne sais pas" rather than the current, oral "chais pas"). They'd use rare words on an everyday basis etc.

Basically, they'd sound like we write. And now that I think about think, politicians' speeches sound that way.

It's a very fine line between classy and pedantic however. And to be fair, the use of French words in English crosses that line for me.