# Is there a particular historical reason French has so much vocabulary to directly lend to other languages?

Tags: vocabulaire, histoire, comparaison-de-langues, emprunts

I often marvel at the direct impact that French has had on other Romance languages (e.g., Spanish). I know that French borrows from these languages as well, but its own lexical influence seems much larger. Were intellectual and literary spaces in France historically so much more productive compared to the rest? Was borrowing from French seen as superior rather than using or creating local terms? Or is there no reason in particular?

Comment: In Europe, French used to play a role similar to the one English plays worldwide nowadays but your question should probably better be asked at https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Got this. Thank you!

Comment: French remained the language of diplomacy for several centuries, see e.g. [here](https://www.legallanguage.com/legal-articles/language-of-diplomacy/). And let's not forget that English is now the world's most widely spoken language, but from 1066 onwards French was the language of the king of England and its court for four centuries.

Comment: Related to your question. https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24724/what-languages-are-perceived-as-classy-or-fancy-to-french-speakers. See the answers therein.